# Different objects for the same class initiated with same value while working with attrs module

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-attrs

I'm trying to create Model class with [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) module. I'm generating `iid` value with bson `ObjectId` which returns a unique value with every call. And generating `timestamp` value with `time` module.

While I was creating two objects with the `User` class, I'm seeing that both objects have same value. But they are initialized separately.

The sample code is here:

```py
from bson import ObjectId
from attrs import asdict, define, field, validators
import time


@define
class CollectionModel:
    """ Base Class For All Collection Schema"""
    iid : str =  str(ObjectId())
    timestamp : float = time.time()

    def get_dict(self):
        return asdict(self)

@define
class User(CollectionModel):
    username : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str)) 
    userType : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str)) 
    password : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str))


user_object1 = User()
user_object2 = User()

print(user_object1)
print(user_object2)
```

The output:

```
User(iid='620bf6910e5fa38f757e35ec', timestamp=1644951185.428748, username='', userType='', password='')
User(iid='620bf6910e5fa38f757e35ec', timestamp=1644951185.428748, username='', userType='', password='')
```

Here, `iid` and `timestamp` is same for both `user_object1` and `user_object2`. But expected different. Although the objects are created separately why the values are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default `iid` is constant because you didn't wrap `str(ObjectId())` into an `attrs.Factory`. It's created once when the class is defined & used in all instances. Same with `timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks @hynek . My problem is solved in this way `_id : str =   field(converter=str, default=Factory(ObjectId))`. Same with `timestamp`

Comment: @carl JFTR you can simplify that to `field(converter=str, factory=ObjectId)`